# OpenCV android: App crashes when applying opencv filter

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm trying to simply load an image and then trying to apply a filter to it using OpenCV, but my app keeps crashing. My image is saved in Drawable as test.jpg.

To apply the filter, I'm first loading the image to the app using `ImageView`. This part is working fine. Then, on click of a button, the filter should be applied to the image. As soon as I click the button, the app crashes.

The code of mainactivity.java is below:

```
package com.xyz.hello;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OpenCVLoader.initDebug();
    }

    public void displayToast(View v){
        Mat img = null;

        try {
            img = Utils.loadResource(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.test);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Imgproc.cvtColor(img, img, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGRA);

        Mat img_result = img.clone();
        Imgproc.Canny(img, img_result, 80, 90);
        Bitmap img_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(img_result.cols(), img_result.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(img_result, img_bitmap);
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.img);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(img_bitmap);
    }

}
```

Also, my .xml file code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">


<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/display_message"
    android:onClick="displayToast"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/test"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true">

</ImageView>
```

Logcat file is repeating this output:

```
2021-03-11 22:01:51.979 6551-6623/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox I/HotwordLSAdapter: getAudioSourceOpeningStatus completed: 102
2021-03-11 22:01:51.979 6551-6623/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 393244, bug: 0]: errorCode: 393244, engine: 0
2021-03-11 22:01:51.980 6551-6623/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
2021-03-11 22:01:51.980 6551-6623/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox I/MicroDetector: #shutdownAudioWithAudioLibrary
2021-03-11 22:01:51.980 6551-13750/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox E/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
2021-03-11 22:01:51.981 6551-6623/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
2021-03-11 22:01:51.982 6551-6623/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox I/HotwordLSAdapter: stopListeningStatus result: 109
```

Comment: `but my app keeps crashing`. Ok, then you have check the logs to see why, right ? Without logs, we can't help you

Comment: @Bruno Edit done

Comment: It is not your package name. You can filter on it to display only related logs